# Access dictionary key value with variable in LUA

Tags: dictionary, variables, lua, roman-numerals

```
local function Numeral(roman) 
  local symbols = {}
  
  local sum = 0

  for i = 1,#roman do
     local val = roman:sub(i,i)
     sum = sum + symbols[val]
  end
  
  return sum
end

print(Numeral('II'))
```

Basically, I'm making a roman numeral to number converter. What I want to do is access a key in a dictionary with a variable like

```
local var = 'I'
local something = dictionary.var
```

But with what I'm doing, it may be a bit more complicated. Is it possible?

Comment: just make a dictionary in an array, where the index is the word

Answer (score 0):

When using a table for the roman numbers then a metatable with the `table` functions in `__index` make things a bit easier.
This example show what i mean...

```
> _VERSION
Lua 5.4
> romans=setmetatable({},{__index=table})
> romans:insert('I')
> romans:insert('II')
> romans:insert('III')
> romans:insert('IV')
> romans:insert('V')
> romans:insert('VI')
> romans:insert('VII')
> romans:insert('VIII')
> romans:insert('VIIII')
> romans:insert('X')
> romans:concat(', ',1,10)
I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, VIIII, X
```

( Done in a interactive Lua console ( lua -i ) )

For more about doing converting from and to roman numbers you can read also...
https://gist.github.com/efrederickson/4080372
But be aware its not free of bugs.
You can do it better ;-)